# maxmind geoip.js is not working? It throws out 401 error

Tags: geolocation

I am using max mind geoip.js. In my website, I used the direct online js. I used it for detecting the country code and depend upon that my website opened.It worked fine.But Now It showing 401 error. I don't know why I got this problem? And Why they blocked?  How can I overcome this problem? Can I use any other geoip js and Is there any free geoip js available?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

MaxMind no longer offers a free JavaScript service. In order to use the JS service, you need to [purchase credits](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-services). If you want free GeoIP, I would recommend either using a [GeoLite downloadable database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) or using a service like [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/), which provides GeoLite data as a free web service, including as JSONP for use in JavaScript.